# Checking if an email already exists in Firebase Auth in Flutter App

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

It works when signing up through email and password but when I use an id that is already registered to signup, it won't show an error. Instead, it redirects to the homepage, and in the console it says `PlatformException(ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE, The email address is already in use by another account`

```
Future validateForm() async {
FormState formState = _formKey.currentState;
if (formState.validate()) {
  FirebaseUser user = await firebaseAuth.currentUser();
  if (user == null) {
    firebaseAuth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _emailTextController.text,
            password: _passwordTextController.text)
        .then((user) => {
              _userServices.createUser(user.user.uid, {
                "username": _nameTextController.text,
                "email": _emailTextController.text,
                "userId": user.user.uid,
                "gender": gender,
              }),
            })
        .catchError((err) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("User Already Exists"),
              content: Text(err.message),
              actions: [
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Ok"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          });
    });
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
  } else {
    return ("already a user");
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are going to the second page, because you have:

```
   Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
```

After the `if` block. So if `user == null` it will enter the `if` then go inside the `catchError` and then navigate to the `HomePage`, you should move the above code to the `else`:

```
  } else {
  Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
    return ("already a user");
  }
```

Comment: let see my database codeimport 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class UserServices {
  FirebaseDatabase _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  String ref = "users";

  createUser(String uid, Map value) {
    _database
        .reference()
        .child("$ref/$uid")
        .set(value)
        .catchError((e) => {print(e.toString())});
  }
}